# Readmore.js doesn't work after loading AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm currently using [Readmore.js](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/) plugin and can't seem to make it work with AJAX content.

```
<td><div class="more"><?php echo $row['book_desc'];?></div></td>
```

**js file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "/func/admin/books.php";
    function loadBooks() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "post",
            data: {
                action: "load"
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#books").hide().html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }
    loadBooks();
    $(".more").readmore();
});
```

I have also included jQuery and Readmore.js files.

I've done the code below (the read more link appeared, but apparently didn't cut `.more`'s content). I shouldn't have been calling the function inside the ajax call, but I just thought it will work lol.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "/func/admin/books.php";
    function loadBooks() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "post",
            data: {
                action: "load"
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#books").hide().html(data).fadeIn();
                $(".more").readmore();
            }
        });
    }
    loadBooks();
});
```

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: @NidhinChandran html is already included above. If you meant about script tags, I will add them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I used mockajax plugin to mock ajax request. Check the ajax function

```js
var data = "From this distant vantage point, the Earth might not seem of any particular interest. But for us, it's different. Consider again that dot. That's here. That's home. That's us. On it everyone you love, everyone you know, everyone you ever heard of, every human being who ever was, lived out their lives. The aggregate of our joy and suffering, thousands of confident religions, ideologies, and economic doctrines, every hunter and forager, every hero and coward, every creator and destroyer of civilization, every king and peasant, every young couple in love, every mother and father, hopeful child, inventor and explorer, every teacher of morals, every corrupt politician, every superstar, every supreme leader, every saint and sinner in the history of our species lived there – on a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam. From this distant vantage point, the Earth might not seem of any particular interest. But for us, it's different. Consider again that dot. That's here. That's home. That's us. On it everyone you love, everyone you know, everyone you ever heard of, every human being who ever was, lived out their lives. The aggregate of our joy and suffering, thousands of confident religions, ideologies, and economic doctrines, every hunter and forager, every hero and coward, every creator and destroyer of civilization, every king and peasant, every young couple in love, every mother and father, hopeful child, inventor and explorer, every teacher of morals, every corrupt politician, every superstar, every supreme leader, every saint and sinner in the history of our species lived there – on a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam. From this distant vantage point, the Earth might not seem of any particular interest. But for us, it's different. Consider again that dot. That's here. That's home. That's us. On it everyone you love, everyone you know, everyone you ever heard of, every human being who ever was, lived out their lives. The aggregate of our joy and suffering, thousands of confident religions, ideologies, and economic doctrines, every hunter and forager, every hero and coward, every creator and destroyer of civilization, every king and peasant, every young couple in love, every mother and father, hopeful child, inventor and explorer, every teacher of morals, every corrupt politician, every superstar, every supreme leader, every saint and sinner in the history of our species lived there – on a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam.";
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.mockjax({
    url: 'data.json',
    responseText: data,
    responseTime: 1500
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
      $(".more").html(data).readmore({
        speed: 500,
        collapsedHeight: 50
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/Readmore.js/2.1.0/readmore.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.6.2/jquery.mockjax.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="more">
        Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```